# Script windows .bat - Get filenames from some folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with some files. (a.js , b.js , c.js )

I need get all files as string like this :

```
text a.js b.js c.js    (with text)
```

i try this but not works

```
$ECHO NO
FOR /R C:\Directory %F in (*.*) do echo %~nF
```

Comment: From the `FOR` command help: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.**

Comment: What do you expect `$ECHO NO` to do? this does not appear as Windows `cmd` syntax; do you mean [`@echo off`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to show a pure batch:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Var=text "
FOR /R Q:\test\2017-01\18 %%F in (*.*) do Set var=!var! %%~nxF
Echo %var%
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ECHO NO` should be `@ECHO OFF`; other than that, in a batch file, you have to use two percent signs (`%%`) in a `FOR` command:

```
FOR /R C:\Directory %%F in (*.*) do echo %%~nF
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged with PowerShell. Here is a PowerShell one-liner:

```
"text $((gci C:\Directory -File).name -join " ")"
```

Comment: but i want to take all files ( i cant add 400 files manually)

Comment: `gci C:\Directory -File` retrieves all the files in `C:\Directory`. So I don't know where are "manually adding files"